# Getting started with wxWidgets and VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wxwidgets

I want to build C++ desktop applications using visual studio and wxWidgets on windows 7.  I'm coming from C++ Builder.

I downloaded and built the wxWidgets libraries successfully and I can run the minimal_vc14 solution just fine. Now it comes time to create my Hello World app. I've created a new, empty C++ project and using NuGet added the wxWidgets template. Then I use class wizard to add a new class (Test3) with a base class of wxApp.

I immediately get 45 errors. The first of which is

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      cannot open source file "../../../lib/vc_dll/mswud/wx/setup.h"  Test3   c:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include\msvc\wx\setup.h  121
```

digging into that file I find the following bit. The last include statement is the problem line identified above, but the problem I think is in the wxConcat6 statement. All of those ../ lead nowhere. Shouldn't that point to $(WXWIN)?

```
// the real setup.h header file we need is in the build-specific directory,
// construct the path to it
#ifdef wxSUFFIX
    #define wxSETUPH_PATH \
        wxCONCAT6(../../../lib/, wxLIB_SUBDIR, /, wxTOOLKIT_PREFIX, wxSUFFIX, /wx/setup.h)
#else // suffix is empty
    #define wxSETUPH_PATH \
        wxCONCAT5(../../../lib/, wxLIB_SUBDIR, /, wxTOOLKIT_PREFIX, /wx/setup.h)
#endif

#define wxSETUPH_PATH_STR wxSTRINGIZE(wxSETUPH_PATH)

#include wxSETUPH_PATH_STR
```

Also, smaller problem but further up the setup.h file I see that WXUSINGDLL has been defined, but I want to use libs. I can't figure out where that is being set either.

Obviously there is a configuration step I missed somewhere. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual the answer can be found by reading EVERYTHING.

There are 2 things that need to be configured for this process to work correctly.

1. After creating the project go to the project properties and set the character set to Unicode. The default is Multi-Byte. My next quest will be to find where to change the default!
2. After installing the package template (or is it a template package?) go to the project properties and set shared to "statically linked build".

[image]

3. Presto changeo, you are ready to go. Add the following for the absolute minimum to make a compilable application. This is based on the tutorial here:[creating-wxwidgets-programs-with-visual-studio-2015](https://usingcpp.wordpress.com/2016/01/26/creating-wxwidgets-programs-with-visual-studio-2015/)

   ```
   bool MyProjectApp::OnInit()
   {
       wxFrame* mainFrame = new wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, L"MyProject");
       mainFrame->Show(true);
       return true;
   }
   wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyProjectApp);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a copy of `minimal` sample (or `widgets`, as it uses more controls and links more libs), in the same location, and modify the source file as you need.

When you have played enough with it, for sure you'll find it quite easy to change the project file so that it'll use `$(WXWIN)` or any other custom settings.

p.s. I don't know what "wxWidgets template" from NuGet contains, but I strongly doubt it is provided by wxWidgets maintainers.

Comment: I've already played with minimal. The example from the tutorial I mentioned in my answer is much more minimal than that, and I like the do it yourself aspect. The template I referenced is in fact referred to on the wxwidgets wiki site, so I think it's legit.

Comment: No, like every wiki, it is mostly written by contributors. And that article makes no exception.